# Which one of the following is true of this relation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, relations

Consider the set of A all the people who are living down Italy."x lives in the same house as y" is a relation on the set A.Consider the following properties of a relation on a set:

a)Symmetric b)Reflexive c)Transitive

So which one is true?

1. a
2. b
3. c
4. a and b
5. all of a,b,c

Please explain how to solve this.Thanks!
p.s.:-Please mention any good Ebook or Web Site to refer about "Relation & Function"

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Most of those who answer questions here are not interested in giving answers to homework unless there is some evidence that the questioner has thought about the problem. So, how far have you got. Which of $a,b,c$ do you think holds and which not?

Comment: @almagest I thought answer would be (according to my knowledge.I'm not very fluent in "Relations & Function" topic) 4.a and b.But that answer is wrong.By the way now i think it is 1.a and I can't sure about it.

Comment: Ok. So look at $a,b,c$ in turn. It is obviously symmetric. It is obviously reflexive ($x$ lives in the same house as $x$), and obviously transitive (if $x,y$ live together, and $y,z$ live together, then $x,z$ live together - we assume people only live in one house, although that is arguably not true). Incidentally, if 4. is true, then 1. and 2. are also true. 1. is not "only $a$ is true". Of course, a badly drafted question might require you to pick only one of the five and mark you wrong if you picked 1. even though others were true too.

Comment: @almagest Thanx for your help and I kindly ask you mention any good Ebook or Web Site to refer about "Relation & Function"

Comment: There is nothing much more to say about relations. The only really important ones are ordering relations (partial and total orders) and equivalence relations. "Functions" is a huge subject. Many mathematicians spend their entire lives in a tiny part of that field! Oh, remember to accept @ConMan's answer (which is correct). The system needs answers to be accepted (if they are correct) so that they can be cleared off the unanswered pile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symmetric: $xRy \iff yRx$

Is it fair to say that the statements "$x$ lives in the same house as $y$" and "$y$ lives in the same house as $x$" are equivalent? If so, then the relation is symmetric.

Reflexive: $xRx$

Is it always true that "$x$ lives in the same house as $x$"? If so, then the relation is reflexive.

Transitive: $xRy \wedge yRz \implies xRz$

If you are given the two statements "$x$ lives in the same house as $y$" and "$y$ lives in the same house as $z$", can you conclude "$x$ lives in the same house as $z$"? If so, then the relation is transitive.

There is a possible interpretation that would suggest that (c) is the only one not necessarily true (if a person can live in two houses), but absent of that possibility then all three are true.

Comment: Thanx for your help and well Explained.